# UICollectionView not fully updating to new layout when variable itemSize used

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uicollectionview

This is probably a bug in`UICollectionView`, and as soon as Apple's bug reporting website stops being broken I will report it. But I thought I'd put this out there in case anybody has had any luck getting around it.

I have a `UICollectionView` displaying some cells using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. I'm using the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol to specify the itemSize for each cell, but I'm using the layout's `sectionInset` property to set section insets.

I need to animate the section inset of the collection view. To do this, I'm creating a new `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` instance, setting its sectionInset property, and calling `-setCollectionViewLayout:animated:` on the collectionView.

The problem is: **If a section of the collection view has items with varying size, that section doesn't update to the new `sectionInset`.** If I just use the layout's itemSize property or if I return a static size from the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method, the section animates correctly. It's only when the section contains items of different heights that it doesn't update.

Seems pretty clearly to be a bug, but I'm still open to the possibility that I'm doing something wrong. `UICollectionView` is really flexible, and the documentation isn't that great, so maybe there's something I'm missing.

Anybody else seen this issue? Any luck getting past it?

**UPDATE**

I've found that the circumstances under which this issue occurs are more specific than what I stated above. The items in the offending section must be wide enough to ensure only one item per row of the vertically-scrolling collection view. Under these circumstances, if **either** the width or height of the items in the section is not uniform, the section's sectionInset is not updated properly

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or workaround?